# More informative asserts in Scala

Tags: unit-testing, scala, assert, googletest

I'm looking for asserts in the style of Google's [testing framework](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/), where something like ASSERT_LT(a, b) will check that $a is less than $b, and if not, will print the values of $a and $b in the error message. The asserts I've found so far just stop execution without printing anything useful by default. Any pointers?

Bonus: I like to write assertion-heavy code (not just in the tests), so it would be nice if the assertions are quick to evaluate.

Context: I came across this when writing unittests using [this code](http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_junit_4) as a template.

Comment: You linked to the ScalaTest framework. Are you saying that when a ScalaTest assertion fails, it doesn't print a useful error message? Or are you saying you want something like ScalaTest without actually using ScalaTest? If the latter, how come you don't want to use it?

Comment: I'm saying ScalaTest doesn't appear to have everything I want. This might me a matter of me not understanding what's available in ScalaTest, but the only informative operator I see is "===" which can only be used when asserting equality. I would like to assert an inequality and get an informative error message if the assert fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Specs2](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/) defines a number of matchers such as `must be_<=`. At first I thought these needed to integrated into a specification, but at the bottom of the [matchers page](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Matchers+guide) it says that they are modular functionality that "*you should be able to reuse in your own test
framework*". As an example, "*You can reuse* [traits such as] `org.specs2.matcher.MustMatchers` *to write anything like* `1 must be_==(1)` *and
get a Result back*".

[ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) has its own [matchers](http://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc-1.6.1/#org.scalatest.matchers.MustMatchers), as well. For example, `one must be < (7)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def assert_<[A <% Ordered[A]](a: => A, b: => A) { 
  assert(a < b, "Assertion failed: expected %s < %s" format (a, b)) 
}

scala> assert_<(2, 1)
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Assertion failed: expected 2 < 1
```